# How does .get() work under the hood of Django?

Tags: sql, django, get

I'm trying to wrap my head around how django's .get() function works; it cant just be a simple LIMIT 1 because the exception it throws gives you the exact number of objects returned. So does django do a COUNT first and then a LIMIT 1? I'm not an SQL expert so I don't know if there's a better way to do it

Comment: https://github.com/django/django/blob/ba4389a36b5fb1afce0cddb4e28233138b6612b7/django/db/models/query.py#L430 it's the count of actually returned rows.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually the count of returned rows number. Check for [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ba4389a36b5fb1afce0cddb4e28233138b6612b7/django/db/models/query.py#L409).

Comment: okay, thanks. so it looks like it does a LIMIT 20 and if the len is greater than 1 it throws and if it's 0 it throws. perfect. thanks! i didn't know where to look in the django source code